# My animation won't render past frame one. I've tried everything in the book. Any suggestions?

Tags: rendering

[image]https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/91919

Here is the blender file. I am not sure what's wrong with the animation process. I've switched back and forth from GPU and CPU mode. I've trying toggling sequence on/off, tried moving the camera. All things are in viewpoint of the camera. No objects are in the way of the camera. There is nothing in the video sequencer and all settings are correct. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's rendering fine to me, it lags at 100% at takes a while to process, probably to you takes longer, I have a good pc and it takes 10 sec per frame to render, you might not have a decent computer so what I would do is render overnight

Comment: I just built a REALLY expensive comouter specifically for animation and music. I have no clue why it won't work for me.

Comment: Did you set anything in blender compositor? It render image immediately- less than 0,3 second, but after render is finished, Blender do post process. That is all right if you set it. What is strange - I have no idea where, because I can't see any nodes in compositor. Maybe it's feature of BI, and I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I have no clue. It renders the first frame in less than 10 seconds and then just stops on the second frame and won't even try to process it. i can post a screen shot of the node editor as well as a screen share of what it does during the rendering process.

Comment: Please don't post your file in a site that requires a login to download. You can upload it at http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then paste the resulting link as part of your question.